# android studio doesnt build cannot run program

Tags: android, android-studio

After creating a new project, I met the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\build-tools-22.0.1\aapt.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:154)
at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:105)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
```

I read that it can be beacuse of the space in the file path. But the path does not contain any spaces. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you can replace `'-'` with `'_'` or just don't use `'-'`.

Answer (score 0):

I once have same problem.
solved it by change the "Android SDK Build Tool" version 18.0.2 to 18.0.1 .
upgrade or downgrade "Android SDK Build Tool" version may solve it as me.
[File-> Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3q8y.jpg)